# Prove that $[\gamma_i(G),\gamma_j(G)] \subseteq \gamma_{i+j}(G)$

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that $[\gamma_i(G),\gamma_j(G)] \subseteq \gamma_{i+j}(G)$ for an arbitrary group $G$ and $\gamma_k(G)$ its lower central series.
I thought to use induction. The induction step was no problem:
\begin{equation}
[\gamma_i(G),\gamma_1(G)] = [\gamma_i(G),G] = \gamma_{i+1}(G) \subseteq \gamma_{i+1}(G)
\end{equation}
Then I supposed that it holds for all $j<k$.
Unfortunately I could not derive the inclusion
\begin{equation}
[\gamma_i(G),\gamma_k(G)] \subseteq \gamma_{i+k}(G)
\end{equation}
Can someone please help?

Comment: You need to use $\gamma_k(G) = [\gamma_{k-1}(G),\gamma_1(G)]$ together with the three subgroups lemma for commutators.

Comment: A proof is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558846/nilpotency-class-of-subgroup?noredirect=1), using the three subgroups lemma. Hence it is an (almost) duplicate.

Comment: Same question here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993422/why-lower-central-series-imply-n-series/)